# Spring MVC @RequestMapping for class level and method level not working

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I try put 2 request mapping since i want to point to home/home since later i will be having another controller with same name which is about/home. But i not sure why it was not working. If have only home it is working but home/home or about/home not working. The class level not working.

This the controller

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.constant.server.HelperConstant;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController 
{
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String doDisplayPage()
    {
        return HelperConstant.VIEW_HOME;
    }

}
```

This the jsp

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="home/home">
        <input type="text" name="t1"><br>
        <input type="text" name = "t2"><br>
        <input type ="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am hitting HTTP Status 404 -

Edited

Attached the config files

```
package com.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[] {SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}
```

This another config file

```
package com.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.controller"})
public class SpringConfig 
{
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver vr = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        //vr.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        vr.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return vr;
    }

}
```

Attached the picture of the folder structure
[image]

there is an additional findings as well whereby i trying to look for the jsp at home/home.jsp. can i know why such behaviour? by right should just look at home.jsp. If remvoe class level anotation, then it working fine or i create a folder inside webapp home it working fine but after click submit again it looks for home/home/home.jsp

I have added a method="POST"

now problem is after restart tomact

[image]

after click submit like this

[image]

if click submit again show eror 404

[image]

this my web.xml but i removed it already since i already use java or configurtion

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

   <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>home.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? any error?

Comment: HTTP error 404. stating it not found the jsp which it looking for home/home.jsp. But why need look into the folder home and search for home.jsp

Comment: why not remove class level annotation and also change `form action="home"`?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer well it's weird. have you tried `/home/home` for `action` attribute?

Comment: Default request mapping method is 'GET' method. Form submit uses 'POST' method by default. You can set method to POST

Comment: @user7294900 the reason put class level as the jsp can have same name for the method call. so to differentiatedi used class level

Comment: @HMD i trieed that too in the jsp

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız so i set to post in method level and class level? what about if there is another jsp calling for controller get method. if i put post it will imapct other jsp?

Comment: You can give multiple method options. And you can give it in class level or method level its depends on your software design

Comment: <form action="home/home"> i tried, method level @RequestMapping(value = "home", method = RequestMethod.POST), class level @RequestMapping(value = "home"). but still not working got HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported; message :Request method 'GET' not supported;
description: The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer did you try my answer?

Comment: @DotBatch hi, it show s HTTP Status 404 - when click submit for first time. localhost:8080/web_main/$%7BhomeUrl%7D?t1=2&t2=2 –

Comment: What is the value of HelperConstant. VIEW_HOME ?

Comment: @javaGroup456 public static String VIEW_HOME = "home"; this the value

Comment: For your form you need to create a post path. Create method with annotation as
 @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doDisplayPage() {}

Comment: @PankajGupta can i knwo what u mean in form create a post path? in method i got try adding post method previously as well but was not working

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, form will use POST action /home/home. On submit doDisplayPage() will be called and it redirects to HelperConstant.VIEW_HOME. Looks like this is not happening and after every click the page get redirected with addition of /home to the existing path . Looks like there is a problem in redirection. Check why you are getting redirected to /home/home/home and whether your action with POST method is even being called or not

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your action path `<form action="home/home">` This is a relative path meaning it will do the following.

```
http://example.com/web_main/home - form action - > 
http://example.com/web_main/home/home (200) - form action -> 
http://example.com/web_main/home/home/home (404)
```

Others are suggesting `/home/home` but that isn't taking to account your application context path. The following would be the result.

```
http://example.com/web_main/home - form action - > http://example.com/home/home
```

Notice that the `web_main` is gone.

To fix your issue you need to leverage JSTL, add this to the JSP.

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:url value="/home/home" var="homeUrl" />`
<form action="${homeUrl}">
```

Add the import to the top of the JSP.

Comment: hi, it show s HTTP Status 404 - when click submit for first time. http://localhost:8080/web_main/$%7BhomeUrl%7D?t1=2&t2=2

Comment: i already add the dependency in maven 
<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
     <version>1.2</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: i added inside head <head>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:url value="/about/home" var="homeUrl" />
</head>  then it was working. Thanks ya

Comment: @Software Engineer 
`<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`
is an import that you add to the top of the jsp file.

Comment: if you want, upload to github and i can make a comment directly

Answer (score 1):

There is one issue in the url.
Have you observed the actual url?
It is displaying /home/home/home after the context but url points to /home/home.
Solution might be removing one /home from the action url in the form tag

```
<html>
<body>
    <form **action="home"**>
        <input type="text" name="t1"><br>
        <input type="text" name = "t2"><br>
        <input type ="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

or

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="/home/home">
        <input type="text" name="t1"><br>
        <input type="text" name = "t2"><br>
        <input type ="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i followed urs for the head section and @Dot Batch solution. Thanks ya

Answer (score 0):

What does your Spring app class look like? If you do not have one you should create one.
Instead of having the `@ComponentScan` below the `@Configuration` tag, do something like below and it should be picked up easier, also maybe change your root tag to just `/` for easier for reading:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.*"})
class MyClass {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(MyClass.class)
   }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController 
{
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String doDisplayPage()
    {
        return HelperConstant.VIEW_HOME;
    }

}
```

Comment: hi mine is spring mvc. Need do like this?

Answer (score 0):

When using `RequestMapping` default request mapping `method` value is `GET` method. Html form submit uses `POST` method by default. So you need to add post method to this url. You can give multiple method value for same request mapping.

Comment: <form action="home/home"> i tried, method level @RequestMapping(value = "home", method = RequestMethod.POST), class level @RequestMapping(value = "home"). but still not working got HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported; message :Request method 'GET' not supported;
description: The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.

Comment: You need to add post method on method level. And remove it from class level

Comment: Do you have any root url path ? If you have it you need to add it in form

Comment: i tried adding post method previously as well but was not workign

Comment: what is as root url?

Answer (score 0):

This is works

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home")
    public String doDisplayPage() {
        return "../home";
    }
}
```

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/about")
public class AboutController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home")
    public String doDisplayPage() {
        return "../home";
    }
}
```

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="/home/home">
        <input type="text" name="t1"><br>
        <input type="text" name = "t2"><br>
        <input type ="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Also you don't need web.xml since you have describe deployment descriptor in your WebConfig and SpringConfig

Comment: hi still not working http://localhost:8080/web_main/home?t1=&t2=
message

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: are you using localhost:8080/web_main/home to open the page for the first time before click submit? where is "web_main" came from? I did not see in your configuration

Comment: in the answer I wrote I use localhost:8080/home/home to open the page, then when submit is clicked, it will return to the same method and load localhost:8080/home/home again. The same handling is also happen with localhost:8080/about/home and both address load the same home.jsp.

Comment: yup i using  localhost:8080/web_main/home.jsp to open it first time. Then 2nd tiem submit becomes  localhost:8080/web_main/home/home.jsp and 3rt time  localhost:8080/web_main/home/home/home.jsp error 404/ web_main is the filder i created (project name)

Comment: i got share u the web,xml but i removed it since not using since java i used for anotation based. But i got share u we,xml i use previously before deletetion

Comment: OK I see now, I have edit my answer too. First, you have to change form action into "/home/home" in home.jsp, then in the return value of doDisplayPage method you should use "../", the return value should became this "../home".

Answer (score 0):

in  404 tab there are 3 home not 2 as you want in URL   so its showing 404 .
Instead of relative path **home/home** in submit form give absolute **/home/home**

Comment: yup this correct but why showing 3 home? by right should only be 1 home since it in home.jsp in webapp

Comment: it is due to redirection from application that URL is changed to home/home not to jsp which it is redirecting

Answer (score 0):

If you are only trying to make your current code work, then a simple solution is to append Context Root to your form action as shown below.

```
<html>
<head>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<c:set var="ctx" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
</head>
<body>
    <form action="${ctx}/home/home">
        <input type="text" name="t1"><br> <input type="text"
            name="t2"><br> <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```